# Execute terminal command at a specific location in Java application

Tags: java

Currently I have a java Netbean project (os X environment). If I use this code to execute the ls command line:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("./test.py");
```

It will execute the command in the root directory of the netbean project(/project). A problem is that I put that test.py in another sub folder (/project/data). So if I use like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("./data/test.py");
```

I have a problem with dependencies I use in test.py, which is also located in data sub folder. I try something likes:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("cd data");
pr = rt.exec("./test.py");
```

but it did not work... So my question is that is there any way to execute command line in that sub folder instead of copying everything to the root folder? (quite messy).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
rt.exec("cd data; ./test.py");
```

To run it in the same command line?

EDIT: and like that?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./test.py", null, new File("data"));
```

The third argument is the context folder of the command.

Comment: I just looked at the Runtime object, you avec a version of the exec method to specify the folder where you want your command ran:

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(null, args, null);